# javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException caught during processing of APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2

Tags: jsf, valuechangelistener

I have two froms in my JSF page the first one to change the language of this page and the second from to submit the form to welcome page.

```
<h:form>
<h:selectOneMenu  onchange="submit()"
        valueChangeListener="#{lang.currentLanguage}" immediate="true">
        <font color="blue"><f:selectItems value="#{lang.localeMap}" /> </font>
    </h:selectOneMenu>

</h:form>

<h:form>    
    <table width="50%" align="left" border="1" cellpadding="5"  
        cellspacing="2">


        <tr>
            <td width="30%"><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.FName}" /></td>
            <td width="70%"><h:inputText value="#{registerBeans.FName}"
                    id="FName" required="true" requiredMessage=" first name inValid"
                    validatorMessage="firt name out of range">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="10" />

                </h:inputText></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td width="30%"><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.SName}" /></td>
            <td width="70%"><h:inputText value="#{registerBeans.sname}"
                    id="SName" required="true" requiredMessage=" second name inValid"
                    validatorMessage="second name out of range">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="10" />

                </h:inputText></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td width="30%"><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.mail}" /></td>
            <td width="70%"><h:inputText value="#{registerBeans.mail}"
                    id="e-mail" required="true" requiredMessage=" e-mail inValid"
                     >
                    </h:inputText> </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td width="30%"><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.password}" /></td>
            <td width="70%"><h:inputSecret
                    value="#{registerBeans.password}" id="password" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="password not found"
                    validatorMessage="pasword out of range">
                    <f:validateLength maximum="20" minimum="4" />

                </h:inputSecret></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="30%"><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.Birthday}" /></td>
            <td width="70%"><h:inputText value="#{registerBeans.birthday}"
                    id="birthday" required="true" requiredMessage="birthday invalid"
                    converterMessage="enter your birthday As dd/mm/yyyy">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/mm/yyyy" />

                </h:inputText></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="30%"><h:outputLabel value="#{msg.GENDER}" /></td>
            <td width="70%"><h:selectOneRadio
                    value="#{registerBeans.gender}" required="true" id="radio"
                    requiredMessage="please choose male OR femal">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.male}" itemValue="male" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.Female}" itemValue="female" />

                </h:selectOneRadio></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" colspan="2">



     <h:commandButton action="#{registerBeans.addStudent()}" value="#{msg.register}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"> 
            <h:messages style="color:red"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</h:form>
```

Here my Managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class lang {
    private Map<String,Locale> localeMap;

    public Map<String, Locale> getLocaleMap() { 

        localeMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Locale>();
        localeMap.put("English", Locale.ENGLISH);
        localeMap.put("Arabic", new Locale("ar"));

        return localeMap;
    }

    public void setCurrentLanguage(ValueChangeEvent evt) {

        String newLang = evt.getNewValue().toString();
        System.out.println(newLang);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Locale> entry : localeMap.entrySet()) {

            if (entry.getValue().toString().equals(newLang)) {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale((Locale)entry.getValue());
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

But I got the following exception when I add immediate attribute:

```
  javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException caught during processing of APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2 : UIComponent-ClientId=j_idt5:j_idt6, Message=Method not found: mypackage.language.lang@172134f.currentLanguage()
  SEVERE: Method not found: mypackage.language.lang@172134f.currentLanguage()   mypackage.language.lang@172134f.currentLanguage()
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
<h:form>
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{registerBeans.locale}" >

        <f:selectItems value="#{registerBeans.localeMap}"/>
        <f:ajax listener="#{registerBeans.addCurrentLanguage()}" render="fname sname mail pass birth gender reg"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGrid columns="2">



        <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.FName}" id="fname"/>
        <h:inputText value="#{registerBeans.FName}"
                    id="FName" required="true" requiredMessage=" first name inValid"
                    validatorMessage="firt name out of range">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="10" />
        </h:inputText>      

        <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.SName}" id="sname"/>
        <h:inputText value="#{registerBeans.LName}"
                    id="LName" required="true" requiredMessage=" last name inValid"
                    validatorMessage="last name out of range">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="10" />
        </h:inputText>      


        <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.mail}" id="mail" />
        <h:inputText value="#{registerBeans.mail}"
                id="e-mail" required="true" requiredMessage=" e-mail inValid"
                 >
                </h:inputText>



        <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.password}" id="pass"/>
        <h:inputSecret
                value="#{registerBeans.password}" id="password" required="true"
                requiredMessage="password not found"
                validatorMessage="pasword out of range">
                <f:validateLength maximum="20" minimum="4" />

            </h:inputSecret>


        <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.Birthday}" id="birth"/>
        <h:inputText value="#{registerBeans.birthday}"
                id="birthday" required="true" requiredMessage="birthday invalid"
                converterMessage="enter your birthday As dd/mm/yyyy">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/mm/yyyy" />

            </h:inputText>


        <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.GENDER}" id="gender" />
        <h:selectOneRadio
                value="#{registerBeans.gender}" required="true" id="radio"
                requiredMessage="please choose male OR femal">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.male}" itemValue="male" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.Female}" itemValue="female" />

            </h:selectOneRadio>
    </tr>

</h:panelGrid>  

     <h:commandButton id="reg" action="#{registerBeans.addStudent()}" value="#{msg.register}" />
     <h:messages style="color:red"/>

</h:form>
```

And I change bean to be like this:

```java
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class RegisterBeans {
    private String FName;
    private String SName;
    private String mail;
    private String pass;
    private String gender;
    private Date birth;
    private String locale;

    // here getters and setters

    public Map<String, Locale> getLocaleMap() { 

        localeMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Locale>();
        localeMap.put("English", Locale.ENGLISH);
        localeMap.put("Arabic", new Locale("ar"));

        return localeMap;
    }

    public void addCurrentLanguage() {

        for (Map.Entry<String, Locale> entry : localeMap.entrySet()) {

            if (entry.getValue().toString().equals(locale)) {
              FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale((Locale)entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }       
}
```